# How to get first three characters of a string and last three character of the same string in oracle, and display them, what will be the query?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How to get first three characters of a string and last three character of the same string in oracle, and display them, what will be the query ?

Comment: Do you know how to do the two parts (first three, last three) separately? If so how have you tried to combine them?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114  Pay close attention to the meaning of passing a negative value for the "position" parameter.

Comment: still no oracle query..........i require query this is your credibility don't mind i want query thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr('hellooWorld',0,3)||substr('hellooWorld',length('hellooWorld')-2,3) from dual;
```

Output:

```
helrld
```